# How to find out mouse coordinates (setTimeout issue)?

Tags: jquery

Here's the code that explains it all:

```
$('#elem123').mouseenter(function () {
 setTimeout(function () {
   //what are mouse coords?
 }, 650);           
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Mouse coordinates *after* the 650 ms have elapsed, and relative to the element, I am guessing? (Adapted from http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position)

**[See a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K5ywc/3/)**

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY;
});

$('#elem123').mouseenter(function () {
    var t = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        var localMouseX = mouseX - t.offsetLeft;
        var localMouseY = mouseY - t.offsetTop;
    }, 650);
});
```

Why use `mousemove` and `offsetLeft`? The reason is that the mouse position is only available to us when such an event happens (and only relative to the entire page). jQuery does not provide a more direct way to obtain it.

Answer (score 0):

Read [**Mouse Position**](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position)

Try

```
$('#elem123').mouseover(function (e) {
    var xPos = e.pageX;
    var yPos = e.pageY;
    setTimeout(function () {
       alert(xPos);
       alert(yPos);
    }, 650);           
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wdmP/)

Comment: The point being, you have to fire off a mouse event, like "mousemove" or "click" in order to retrieve the mouse coordinates from the callback function's parameters (e in rahul's example).