# Javascript step event with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am a novice in canvas and I was wondering how can I get a "step" event (e.g. execute every half a second) while able to reference to the mouse position, for example if I want to draw something at the mouse position every 0.5 second independent of the mouse movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to globally bind the `mousemove` event to the document body and save the mouse positions into a publicly accessible variable (like `window.mouseX` and `window.mouseY`).
Then within `setInterval(function () {
    ...
}, 500);`, you can retrieve the values of `window.mouseX` and `window.mouseY`.

As far as I know, there is no other way than to constantly, globally track your mouse's movements, because setInterval doesn't create an event with mouse data for you.

Here is someone else's example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4704204/1381550

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `setInterval(yourFunction, delay)`.
'yourFunction' is well... your function and 'delay' is the interval-time in milli-seconds.

In your case this would look something like:

```
//alway's define stuff before you use it
function drawSomething(){ 
    //your code here
}

window.setInterval(drawSomething, 500); //this is your 0.5 sec stepped interval
```

See (for example) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Good luck!

Comment: I would go for `requestAnimationFrame` instead, see my answer.

Comment: @Fallup: You are right, I added the canvas-tag to the question and upvote [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16020027/588079)!

Answer (score 1):

Use new HTML5 feature `requestAnimationFrame` with canvas instead of `setInterval` and `setTimeout` for better performance. `requestAnimationFrame` for example ensures that when user switch to another tab the animation is paused = saves CPU. 
To support all browsers use shim layer, see example :

```
//shim layer
window.requestAnimFrame =
window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
};

function animate() {   
       requestAnimFrame( animate );        
       draw();   
    }

function draw()    
    {        
      // handle time interval here
      // actual code here
    }
```

For more see (including tips how you can handle time interval) :

- [window.requestAnimationFrame mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame)
- [adobe cook books](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_HTML5_requestAnimationFrame_simple_example-19747.html)
- [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the mouse position every 0.5 seconds using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

```
setInterval(step, 500);

function step() {
  // do your stuff here
}
```

The function `step` will execute every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: How can I get the mouse position within step() though?

Comment: I know that for clarity in this particular case `setInterval()` may be enough, but I would mention `requestAnimationFrame` as a better option.